# 'TypeError: dest.end is not a function' when trying to import rxjs

Tags: gulp, browserify, rxjs

I'm new to both Gulp and Browserify and I'm working on a Typescript project. Everything worked
fine till I imported rxjs but since then I'm facing with the following error message:

```
d:\Work\rxjsnew\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:523
    dest.end();
         ^
TypeError: dest.end is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (d:\Work\rxjsnew\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:523:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at d:\Work\rxjsnew\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:965:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

If I remove the rxjs import, the project is compiled successfully.
This is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var tsify = require("tsify");


gulp.task('scripts', function () {
      return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(browserify().on('error', function(e){
            console.log(e);
         }));
  });

gulp.task("default", ["scripts"], function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: '.',
        debug: true,
        entries: ['src/main.ts'],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
    .plugin(tsify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing '@reactivex/rxjs' package and importing Rx the following way solved the issue.

```
import { Observable } from '@reactivex/rxjs';
```